# AMD Graphics drivers and additional setup using ubuntu

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu

This is my first time using Ubuntu, and I am excited at the prospect of getting away from Windows. I'm worried that I will continue having issues, and be forced to go back.

I've looked at previous topics on the subject of AMD Graphics cards and I am still running into issues. I am suspecting that I did my installation wrong.
I've installed from [here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx) ubuntu 18.20 following instructions from [here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Installation-Instructions-for-amdgpu-Graphics-Stacks.aspx). I also used `./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=pal` as well because I am using a RX 580.

Now two things of note. Unlike windows, I do not see any program relating to the drivers installed that I can use.

I am testing my performance using CS:GO through Steam. Long story short, I am getting down to ~50 fps and up to ~100 fps which is far worse than what was on my windows system using an older graphics card (A 7850 usually running at 120 fps+). Even turning down the settings had no effect on FPS. When starting the game, it also doesn't maximize, and when using multiple screens it goes to the wrong resolution.

My other major concern is that I do not have everything extra installed properly. I have an ivy bridge i5-3450 and I couldn't find any additional drivers for it.

I've looked around at general setup stuff for Ubuntu, and it doesn't seem like there is much beyond this.